# GoogleSignin is failing on some devices

Tags: android

In a nutshell, here's my activityResult handler. But it seems to be failing on some production devices. It is a mix of Android versions from 10, 11, 12 & 13 and a mix of devices including Samsung. I'm clueless here. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Could you post the error that you received?

Comment: First: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Second: you do not describe how "failing" manifests itself: what happens? What error messages (if any) do you get?

Comment: Please test your app on remote test lab devices (https://developer.samsung.com/remote-test-lab) and give the logcat information for better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Here is GoogleSignIn Java Code u can convert to kotlin

```
 GoogleSignInAccount account = null;

 private void signIn() {
    showLoading(true);
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}





  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        showLoading(false);
        try {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            handleSignInResult(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            updateUI(null);
        }
    }
}
```